# Optimal solution for clustering of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, markerclusterer

**I am looking for some approach (algorithm to be very specific) here.**

Problem:There are N rectangles (*r1, r2,.. rn*) scattered in X-Y plane. Need to find optimal solution to cluster these rectangles with bigger bounded polygons.

Condition for clustering:

1. Results should have maximum number of rectangles covered in the polygon.
2. Total count of bounded polygon should be minimum possible and maximum **K**.
3. Each bounded polygon must have at least 70% area filled with given rectangles.
4. All rectangles need not to be bounded.

constraint:

- 1 millions <= n <= billions
- K = 50000

Problem can be thought of as to identify islands (max 50k island) having higher density of rectangles (70% in each island). We can off course exclude certain rectangles. But the idea is to find optimal solution and there is no single best solution.

I was trying to use K-means clustering but it doesn't fit in my case as in my problem solution can lie within 1-K values instead of K values. May be it requires all together different dimension of thinking. Hope I am clear!!

Adding image to be just more clearer:
[image]

Comment: Do the polygons have to be convex?

Comment: No. @DavidEisenstat

Comment: Then one polygon suffices unless you impose some other condition on the polygons (since it's possible for that polygon to surround all of the rectangles with infinitesimal channels connecting them).

Comment: My mistake I should been a bit clearer. I have updated my post with the image. The polygon edges should be the way it is shown in the image. I don't know how to state this requirement. @DavidEisenstat

Comment: Orthogonally convex? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull

Comment: I am not sure is it orthogonally convex as per definition. But the edges should be as shown covering outer boundaries of the rectangles.

Comment: Well, an example doesn't work for writing an algorithm. And you will most likely have to implement it yourself anyway.